# Symfony3 websocket ratchet doctrine query does not work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, websocket, ratchet

I ask my question because I didn't find any answers.

I have a Symfony3 application with a websocket part with Ratchet (cboden/ratchet).

The proccess works fine, but when the ratchet server is running, if I do a persist and flush actions through Doctrine, the transaction seems to be stuck and never ends.
The object is not persisted into the database and can not be read.
But when I stop the ratchet server, the object finnaly appears in the database.

My question is why Doctrine actions doesn't work while ratchet server is running ?

In advance, thank you.

***UPDATE :***
To be clear, I have a symfony command that launch the ratchet (websocket) server. And another Symfony command that takes my data and try to persist them in database. So that's the flush in the second command which never ends.

***UPDATE 2:***
Sorry to up this topic but I really need help...
I do test and test and test but this flush function is stuck.

First :
I launch : php bin/console websocket:ratchet
The starting is good my client can connect I see :
-----------START SOCKET------------
New connection! (1151)

So that's good

Second : 
I start my other command that collect information from a software call Nagios (to get all current alarm) and I want to insert them into my MySQL database so I hydrate my object alarmGI, persist it and try to flush (via Doctrine)...
I think the line is inserted into the database (not sure).
Then I send the AlarmGI object to the ratchet server and try, in the OnMessage function, to get these AlarmGI with the find function and the ID given by the flush....and here the object is not find...why ?

The object was supposed to be flushed just a few seconds ago, even if I put a sleep function between the flush and the find, the object is not find...I don't understand...

Comment: How many processor running have you got on your dev environment ?

Comment: Hi, I'm on a windows environnement with Wamp Server. I have 2 cores with 4 logic processors